Can only create a functional MWAA environment through the UI console, not CDK
I'm trying to create a new MWAA environment through CDK. I'm able to deploy the infrastructure, but the dags won't appear in the Airflow frontend. When I look at the dag processor manager logs I see the following summary:
================================================================================
DAG File Processing Stats

File Path                                         PID  Runtime      # DAGs    # Errors  Last Runtime    Last Run
----------------------------------------------  -----  ---------  --------  ----------  --------------  -------------------
/usr/local/airflow/dags/tutorial.py              1214  40.90s            0           1  54.83s          2024-08-08T17:12:02
/usr/local/airflow/dags/profile_data_update.py                           0           1  60.60s          2024-08-08T17:13:05
================================================================================

I also see timeout messages: Processor for /usr/local/airflow/dags/tutorial.py with PID 1214 started at 2024-08-08T17:12:34.577674+00:00 has timed out, killing it.
From the summary it appears that the dag processors are being killed as they are taking longer than 50 seconds to process these dags. However, I am unable to figure out where or why this timeout is happening, as I can't find any reference to it in other logs.
As an experiment, I created another MWAA environment through the AWS UI console using as many identical resources as possible: networking, working config, execution role. The only difference is in the database vpc endpoint services, but I took a closer look at them and they appear to be functionally identical. This environment is able to correctly process the dags:
================================================================================
DAG File Processing Stats

File Path                                       PID    Runtime      # DAGs    # Errors  Last Runtime    Last Run
----------------------------------------------  -----  ---------  --------  ----------  --------------  -------------------
/usr/local/airflow/dags/tutorial.py                                      1           0  0.68s           2024-08-08T17:16:13
/usr/local/airflow/dags/profile_data_update.py                           1           0  0.87s           2024-08-08T17:16:12
================================================================================

Notice how much faster the runtime is - less than a second. This makes much more sense to me as tutorial.py just calls three different bash operators.
I noticed I am not explicitly setting the endpointManagement property the CDK. Is this something not automatically handled for you if left as default in CDK only?
const mwaaCfnEnvironment = new mwaa.CfnEnvironment(this, 'MwaaEnvironment', {
  name: `CdpAirflow-${props.environment}`,
  airflowVersion: '2.8.1',
  sourceBucketArn: mwaaBucket.bucketArn,
  dagS3Path: 'dags/',
  requirementsS3Path: 'requirements.txt',
  environmentClass: 'mw1.small',
  executionRoleArn: mwaaExecutionRole.roleArn,
  maxWorkers: 10,
  webserverAccessMode: 'PUBLIC_ONLY',
  airflowConfigurationOptions: {
    'core.default_timezone': 'utc',
    'secrets.backend': 'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.secrets.secrets_manager.SecretsManagerBackend',
    'secrets.backend_kwargs': '{"connections_prefix": "airflow/connections", "variables_prefix": "airflow/variables"}'
  },
  loggingConfiguration: {
    dagProcessingLogs: {
      enabled: true,
      logLevel: 'DEBUG'
    },
    schedulerLogs: {
      enabled: true,
      logLevel: 'DEBUG'
    },
    taskLogs: {
      enabled: true,
      logLevel: 'DEBUG'
    },
    webserverLogs: {
      enabled: true,
      logLevel: 'DEBUG'
    },
    workerLogs: {
      enabled: true,
      logLevel: 'DEBUG'
    },
  },
  networkConfiguration: {
    subnetIds: subnetIds,
    securityGroupIds: securityGroupIds
  },
});


Check your network configurations. Especially your CIDR range. Make sure it's not clashing with AWS's reserved range https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-cidr-blocks.html#vpc-sizing-ipv4.

@AzizurRahman the two environments should have identical network configurations
